# Vue js 3 map() is not a function using laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using map() function to return an array for my data and display they in a dynamically way for my table in vue js. I get an error when i use paginate method : map() is not a function.
Here is the vue table with function

```
<thead class="">
<tr>
  <th><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="selectAll" title="Select All"></th>
  <th v-for="(header, index) in visibleHeaders" :key="index" scope="col">
     {{ header }}
  </th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr v-show="leads.length" v-for="(column, index) in visibileColumn" :key="index">
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="selected" :value="column.id" />
  </td>
  <td v-for="atr in column">{{atr}}</td>
  <td>
   <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</a>
   <button type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-secondary"  data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#editUserModal" >Edit</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-danger" >Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr v-show="!leads.length">
  <td colspan="12" class="text-center">Sorry :( No data found.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

//script
data() {
        return {
            headers: [],
            leads: [],
            field: '',
        }
    },

computed: {
        visibleHeaders() {
            return this.headers.map(h => {
                return h.Field.replace("_", " ").toUpperCase()
            });
        },
        visibileColumn() {
            return this.leads.map(c => {
                // console.log(c)
                return c
            })
        },
    },

methods: {
   getData() {
            axios.get('/leads/getleads')
            .then(response => {
                this.leads = response.data.leads
                this.headers = response.data.headers
                // console.log(response.data.leads)
            })
        },
}
```

And laravel controller function

```
public function getleads(Request $request)
    {
        $table_name = 'leads';
        // Through raw query
        $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name";
        $data = DB::select($query);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json([
                'leads' => Lead::paginate(10),
                'headers' => $data
            ], Response::HTTP_OK);
        }
    }
```

if i use `'leads' => Lead::get(),` this method works fine but when i use `paginate(10)` i get an error

```
app.js:34778 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.leads.map is not a function"
```

Comment: Are you sure that this.leads is an array?

Comment: you are right i didnt see this detail. Thank you `response.data.leads.data` is the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `paginate` method returns an object with `data` field and other fields explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json), so you should do :

```js
this.leads = response.data.leads.data
```